# MongoDB 2.6 Update Error

Tags: mongodb

**I am  getting conflict when**

> [root@MongoDB ec2-user]# sudo yum install mongodb-org Loaded plugins:
>   priorities, security, update-motd, upgrade-helper Setting up Install
>   Process Resolving Dependencies
>   --> Running transaction check
>   ---> Package mongodb-org.x86_64 0:2.6.0-1 will be installed
>   --> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-tools = 2.6.0 for package: mongodb-org-2.6.0-1.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-shell = 2.6.0 for package: mongodb-org-2.6.0-1.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-server = 2.6.0 for package: mongodb-org-2.6.0-1.x86_64
>   --> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-mongos = 2.6.0 for package: mongodb-org-2.6.0-1.x86_64
>   --> Running transaction check
>   ---> Package mongodb-org-mongos.x86_64 0:2.6.0-1 will be installed
>   ---> Package mongodb-org-server.x86_64 0:2.6.0-1 will be installed
>   ---> Package mongodb-org-shell.x86_64 0:2.6.0-1 will be installed
>   ---> Package mongodb-org-tools.x86_64 0:2.6.0-1 will be installed
>   --> Processing Conflict: mongodb-org-tools-2.6.0-1.x86_64 conflicts mongo-10gen-server
>   --> Processing Conflict: mongodb-org-tools-2.6.0-1.x86_64 conflicts mongo-10gen
>   --> Processing Conflict: mongodb-org-mongos-2.6.0-1.x86_64 conflicts mongo-10gen-server
>   --> Processing Conflict: mongodb-org-mongos-2.6.0-1.x86_64 conflicts mongo-10gen
>   --> Processing Conflict: mongodb-org-shell-2.6.0-1.x86_64 conflicts mongo-10gen-server
>   --> Processing Conflict: mongodb-org-shell-2.6.0-1.x86_64 conflicts mongo-10gen
>   --> Processing Conflict: mongodb-org-2.6.0-1.x86_64 conflicts mongo-10gen-server
>   --> Processing Conflict: mongodb-org-2.6.0-1.x86_64 conflicts mongo-10gen
>   --> Processing Conflict: mongodb-org-server-2.6.0-1.x86_64 conflicts mongo-10gen-server
>   --> Processing Conflict: mongodb-org-server-2.6.0-1.x86_64 conflicts mongo-10gen
>   --> Finished Dependency Resolution Error: mongodb-org-shell conflicts with mongo-10gen-2.4.10-mongodb_1.x86_64 Error: mongodb-org-server
>   conflicts with mongo-10gen-server-2.4.10-mongodb_1.x86_64 Error:
>   mongodb-org-mongos conflicts with mongo-10gen-2.4.10-mongodb_1.x86_64
>   Error: mongodb-org-mongos conflicts with
>   mongo-10gen-server-2.4.10-mongodb_1.x86_64 Error: mongodb-org-tools
>   conflicts with mongo-10gen-2.4.10-mongodb_1.x86_64 Error:
>   mongodb-org-server conflicts with mongo-10gen-2.4.10-mongodb_1.x86_64
>   Error: mongodb-org-tools conflicts with
>   mongo-10gen-server-2.4.10-mongodb_1.x86_64 Error: mongodb-org
>   conflicts with mongo-10gen-server-2.4.10-mongodb_1.x86_64 Error:
>   mongodb-org conflicts with mongo-10gen-2.4.10-mongodb_1.x86_64 Error:
>   mongodb-org-shell conflicts with
>   mongo-10gen-server-2.4.10-mongodb_1.x86_64  You could try using
>   --skip-broken to work around the problem  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

and update giving this error:

> sudo yum update mongodb-org Loaded plugins: priorities, security,
>   update-motd, upgrade-helper amzn-main
>   | 2.1 kB     00:00      amzn-updates
>   | 2.3 kB     00:00      Setting up Update Process Package(s)
>   mongodb-org available, but not installed.

How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the package name has changed, you do need to remove the old package and install the new one. However, instead of doing this as two steps, it is cleaner to use the yum shell. This  will remove the old package and install the new one in a single transaction:

```
yum shell
> install mongodb-org
> remove mongo-10gen
> remove mongo-10gen-server
> run
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mongo-10gen.i686 0:2.4.10-mongodb_1 will be erased
---> Package mongo-10gen-server.i686 0:2.4.10-mongodb_1 will be erased
---> Package mongodb-org.i686 0:2.6.0-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-tools = 2.6.0 for package: mongodb-org-2.6.0-1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-shell = 2.6.0 for package: mongodb-org-2.6.0-1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-server = 2.6.0 for package: mongodb-org-2.6.0-1.i686
--> Processing Dependency: mongodb-org-mongos = 2.6.0 for package: mongodb-org-2.6.0-1.i686
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mongodb-org-mongos.i686 0:2.6.0-1 will be installed
---> Package mongodb-org-server.i686 0:2.6.0-1 will be installed
---> Package mongodb-org-shell.i686 0:2.6.0-1 will be installed
---> Package mongodb-org-tools.i686 0:2.6.0-1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

================================================================================
 Package                  Arch       Version                 Repository    Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 mongodb-org              i686       2.6.0-1                 10gen        4.6 k
Removing:
 mongo-10gen              i686       2.4.10-mongodb_1        @10gen       181 M
 mongo-10gen-server       i686       2.4.10-mongodb_1        @10gen        30 M
Installing for dependencies:
 mongodb-org-mongos       i686       2.6.0-1                 10gen        6.7 M
 mongodb-org-server       i686       2.6.0-1                 10gen        8.9 M
 mongodb-org-shell        i686       2.6.0-1                 10gen        4.2 M
 mongodb-org-tools        i686       2.6.0-1                 10gen         88 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  1 Package  (+4 Dependent packages)
Remove   2 Packages

Total download size: 108 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: y
Downloading packages:
(1/5): mongodb-org-2.6.0-1.i686.rpm                      | 4.6 kB     00:00
(2/5): mongodb-org-mongos-2.6.0-1.i686.rpm               | 6.7 MB     00:00
(3/5): mongodb-org-server-2.6.0-1.i686.rpm               | 8.9 MB     00:00
(4/5): mongodb-org-shell-2.6.0-1.i686.rpm                | 4.2 MB     00:00
(5/5): mongodb-org-tools-2.6.0-1.i686.rpm                |  88 MB     00:04
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                               19 MB/s | 108 MB  00:05
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : mongodb-org-server-2.6.0-1.i686                              1/7
  Installing : mongodb-org-mongos-2.6.0-1.i686                              2/7
  Installing : mongodb-org-tools-2.6.0-1.i686                               3/7
  Installing : mongodb-org-shell-2.6.0-1.i686                               4/7
  Installing : mongodb-org-2.6.0-1.i686                                     5/7
  Erasing    : mongo-10gen-server-2.4.10-mongodb_1.i686                     6/7
  Erasing    : mongo-10gen-2.4.10-mongodb_1.i686                            7/7
  Verifying  : mongodb-org-2.6.0-1.i686                                     1/7
  Verifying  : mongodb-org-shell-2.6.0-1.i686                               2/7
  Verifying  : mongodb-org-tools-2.6.0-1.i686                               3/7
  Verifying  : mongodb-org-mongos-2.6.0-1.i686                              4/7
  Verifying  : mongodb-org-server-2.6.0-1.i686                              5/7
  Verifying  : mongo-10gen-server-2.4.10-mongodb_1.i686                     6/7
  Verifying  : mongo-10gen-2.4.10-mongodb_1.i686                            7/7

Removed:
  mongo-10gen.i686 0:2.4.10-mongodb_1
  mongo-10gen-server.i686 0:2.4.10-mongodb_1

Installed:
  mongodb-org.i686 0:2.6.0-1

Dependency Installed:
  mongodb-org-mongos.i686 0:2.6.0-1      mongodb-org-server.i686 0:2.6.0-1
  mongodb-org-shell.i686 0:2.6.0-1       mongodb-org-tools.i686 0:2.6.0-1

Finished Transaction
> exit
Leaving Shell
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to remove packages of MongoDB 2.4:

```
 sudo yum remove mongo-10gen*
```

and then install packages of new MongoDB 2.6:

```
sudo yum install mongodb-org
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that you are upgrading from version 2.4 to 2.6 which apparently has changed the package names.

I guess you will have to remove/erase the old package mongodb-10gen* and then run this new install command for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

remove the old mongodb

sudo yum remove mongo-10gen-server mongo-10gen-tools mongo-10gen-shell mongo-10gen-mongos mongo-10gen

install the new mongodb (prerequisitely, you must config the yum source, refer [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat-centos-or-fedora-linux/) )

sudo yum install mongodb-org